# EC2 server can't resolve hostnames

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

When trying to resolve a hostname (i.e. using `dig`), the server almost always fails, saying `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. Around one in ten attempts works, usually after a long waiting time.

Strange thing is that the same behavior happens also if I'm querying a different DNS server (Google's).

My default nameserver is Amazon's, @ 172.31.0.2 . I get this one automatically when the server connects using DHCP.

Pinging the IPs (8.8.8.8 & 172.31.0.2) also *usually* fails.

I've tried checking the VPC settings and security group settings, but found nothing. Also the fact it works every once in a while makes me even more confused.

Comment: have you set resolv.conf properly

Comment: @anish never touched it. `$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.31.0.2
search eu-central-1.compute.internal`

Comment: Are you using a VPC?  What configuration?  Have you create the NAT instance and created the routes?  Can you resolve the hostname that AWS assigned from the DNS?

Comment: @VernBurton the problem disappeared by itself. I guess it was outside the scope of my server, which is running without any changes for about a year now. I've done absolutely no changes to the VPC / NAT settings for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappeared by itself after around 48 hours. I don't know how to further analyize the issue so I'm closing this question. I can't think of anything about the server or AWS configuration that could have caused this, so I assume it was something with AWS's infrastructure.

Thanks